# Image.fromURL error callback

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to load an image using the `fromURL`. The issue is that I'd like it to be able to load a default icon if it is not able to reach the Image server to download the image. Looking at the docs I did not see an error callback for the `fromURL` function. How are we supposed to catch that the call was not successful and therefore do the appropriate thing? It does not seem that the callback gets called at all when image load was unsuccessful.

Comment: why not put the default icon in every case anyway ?

Comment: Even if I did that, I still need the callback to trigger in order to add stuff onto the canvas.

Comment: I believe the latest version of FabricJS supports callbacks now:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#fromURL

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fabric.util.loadImage()` method instead of `fabric.Image.fromURL()`.

If you look at the `fromURL()` method implementation, internally it uses the `loadImage()`.

The following code may help you:

```
fabric.util.loadImage('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kienzle.dev.cors/img/image2.png', function(img) {
    if(img == null) {
        alert("Error!");
    }else {
        var image = new fabric.Image(img);
        canvas.add(image).setActiveObject(image);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/30kmn5kL/

Answer (score 2):

once you have done the function, even if theres a mistake the callback keeps running, then you could check for the element (as other said) in this way:

```
let fabricBackgroundInstance = new fabric.Image.fromURL(imageToUse, (oImg) => {

  if(oImg._element == null){
    console.error('oImg', oImg._element);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the second argument `isError` to your callback function.

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL("your image URL", (img, isError) => {
  if (isError) {
    console.log('Something Wrong with loading image');
    return;
  }
  // do something on success
}
```

Also check fabric.js source code of `Image.fromURL` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line21471

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`getElement()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#getElement) to check this error.

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL('/foo.jpg', (img) => {
  if (img.getElement() === undefined) {
    console.log('Failed to load image!');
    return;
  }
  // do something on success
}
```

Comment: `"fabric": "^2.6.0"` returns empty plain JS Object now.